# Why is my AWS Athena table not following defined schema to fetch data from S3?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I understand that athena reads all the files stored in that folder, i have no issue with that. Let me explain you with data, I have 2 csv files named `dummy.csv` and `test.csv` both in the same s3 folder. `dummy.csv` has 2 columns named `tid` (int) and `tnm` string. similarly test.csv also has two columns `num` (int) and `name` (string). Notice that the column names of both files are completely different. And now I created an Athena table for my data using the following code where pipeline is my database name and test is my table name:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pipeline`.`test` (`num` int, `name` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('field.delim' = ',')
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION 's3://pak1/ISB/Office/FFC/test/dummy/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('classification' = 'csv');
```

After creating the table when I execute this command:

```
SELECT * FROM test;
```

I am expecting Athena to just return me the values from the file that has column names 'num' and 'name' in it, in our case which is test.csv. Instead the output consist of values from both files with ambiguous format. find the attached images output from Athena in response to the query mentioned above. Notice that in output image first three results are from `test.csv` file and the rest are from `dummy.csv` file. Whereas I expected to just fetch the data from `test.csv`.

Why is my Athena table not following the defined schema to fetch data. Note that I've already tried different SerDe operators but that didn't work either.

Output:

[image: output from Athena]

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Athena is not 'smart' enough to look at the headings in the files and figure out which column you are referencing.

Instead, it just assumes that the first two columns in the files will be the first two columns defined in the table DDL (`num` and `name`).

**All files in the directory must have the same format.** It is not possible to do what you are attempting to do. Instead, you would need to create two separate tables with different columns and different input files.

Also, you have not told Athena that the first row is a heading, so the row is being treated as data. To skip the first row you can specify:

```
TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count"="1")
```

Comment: how can i create two separate tables with different input files, as i can only specify location for input folder having multiple csv files.

Comment: If you have input files with different formats, then put them in separate folders and create two tables -- one pointing to each folder. All files in a given `location` (including subdirectories of that location) must have files in the **same format**.